# Pluma shifts displayed text from "find" to left - can that be stopped

Tags: pluma

Like using Pluma more but when doing a "Find/Replace" the entire display of text shifts to the left making it impossible to read the beginning of the line(s). Is there a way to stop this from happening? When "finding" a word, all of the text preceding it is moved to the left so that it can not be easily read! Am forced to use "NotePad" under "wine" to do easier to read word searches that do NOT shift the entire displayed text! VERY Annoying. . .

Comment: Please read  https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting . Take the [tour].